# How can I create this layout that spans multiple rows using Android TableLayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

How would I go about creating the following layout using tablelayout?  Column spanning is straightforward, but I haven't found any clear guidance on row spanning.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one... You can use the layout_weight property to achieve what you are trying to do..
the below layout will have the layout as shown by you in the above picture..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="0dip">
            <View android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#fff"></View>
            <View android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#eee" android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></View>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="0dip">
            <View android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#eee" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"></View>
            <View android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#fff"></View>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow>
            <View android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#bbb" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></View>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
```

In the above code replace the view with the one that you want over there...